# Same CSS rule, different results

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I have a div with an image inside it. I'm trying to centre align it, but it doesn't work. I have another CSS rule that is aligning something else, so i tried applying that and it works! But the content of those rules are the same.

Here is the block in question:

```
<div id = "dlbutton">
    <a href="signup.html"><img src="img/arrow2.png"></a>
</div>
```

Here are the rules:

```
#dlbutton 
{
     font-size: 2em;
     text-align: center;
}

#arrowbutton
{
     font-size: 2em;
     text-align: center;
}
```

when I apply #arrowbutton, it's left aligned, when I apply #dlbutton, its centre aligned. This issue occurs in android chrome, on the "internet" browser on S3, this issue is none-existent.

Comment: If it differs, then you have different styling affecting the elements.
Is it possible to provide more code?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing img src by this

```
<img style= class="align-center" src="img/arrow2.png"/>
```

What your asking css to do is align text which you do not have in the div.

Answer (score 0):

Is #dlbutton lower down on the stylesheet than #arrowbutton? You probably have another rule with greater specificity overwriting the #arrowbutton rule. Inspect the element with a web developer tool and see what style selectors are being applied to the div and the image.

Using text-align on images isn't always going to produce the desired results since different browsers treat images and text-align differently. Probably the best way to reliably center images is to use the following code:

```
.imgcenter {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Then call the imgcenter class on any image you want centered as so:

```
<img class="imgcenter" src="imagelocation/img.jpg" />
```

Or if you want all of your images to be block level centered images then you can just use img instead of a class in your CSS rules as so:

```
IMG {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can also use a pure HTML approach (not recommended) by adding the `<center>` tag.

```
<div id = "dlbutton">
  <center>
    <a href="signup.html"><img src="img/arrow2.png"></a>
  </center>
</div>
```